# lamps probability .

Tags: probability

A room has $3$ lamp sockets. From a collection of $10$ bulbs $,6$ are fused .

A person selects $3$ at random and puts them in sockets. The probability that he will have the light is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Total no. of events $ = $ no. of selecting $3$ lamps out of total $10$ is $ \displaystyle \binom{10}{3}$

Now favourable events $ = $ selecting $3$ bulbs out of total $4$ blubs $\displaystyle = \binom{4}{3}$

So Required probability $\displaystyle  = \frac{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2}{10\cdot 9 \cdot 8} = \frac{1}{30}$

Is my solution is right, If not then how can we solve it,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct if what you meant is "probability that he will have all three lighted".

Answer (score 0):

If the favorable event reads "he takes at least one working bulb", then your answer isn't correct.

Indeed this probability reads $1-\frac{ 6}{ 10}\frac{ 5}{ 9}\frac{ 4}{ 8} = \frac 5 6$ which amount to compute $1-\mbox{Probability of taking only fused bulbs}$.